# function in R (with dplyr)

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I made a R script that works for me, but I know I could make it better (prettier) with the use of functions.  Unfortunately my varied attempts weren't successful.  Could anyone guide me on the right track?  Below is my original script.

```
library(dplyr)

apples <- read.csv("JoburgApples.csv")

grs <- apples %>% filter(grepl("GRANNY", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Granny Smith")
cpp <- apples %>% filter(grepl("PINK", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Cripps Pink")
top <- apples %>% filter(grepl("TOP", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Top Red")
gld <- apples %>% filter(grepl("GOLDEN", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Golden Delicious")
ski <- apples %>% filter(grepl("STARKING", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Starking")
bra <- apples %>% filter(grepl("BRAEBURN", ProductName), tvaluesold >10000) %>% mutate(Variety = "Braeburn")

apples <- rbind(grs, cpp, top, gld, ski, bra)

s70 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("70$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 70)
s80 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("80$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 80)
s90 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("90$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 90)
s100 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("100$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 100)
s110 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("110$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 110)
s120 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("120$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 120)
s135 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("135$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 135)
s150 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("150$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 150)
s165 <- apples %>% filter(grepl("165$", ProductName)) %>% mutate(Count = 165)

apples <- rbind(s70, s80, s90, s100, s110, s120, s135, s150, s165)
```

EDIT.  Link to the .csv file (https://github.com/fderyckel/showcases/blob/master/JoburgMarket/JoburgApples.csv)

```
> UnitMass  ProductName tvaluesold  tquantitysold   tkgsold avgprice    highestprice    date
> 18.50KG CARTON    CRIPPS PINK,CL 1,100    200 1   18.5    200 200 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    CRIPPS RED,CL 1,70  200 1   18.5    200 200 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    TOPRED,CL 1,180 1300    10  185 130 130 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,90    22700   108 1998    210.19  240 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    STARKING,CL 1,80    17920   115 2127.5  155.83  230 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GRANNY SMITH,CL 1,135   1800    12  222 150 150 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    TOPRED,CL 1,90  1730    12  222 144.17  190 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    CRIPPS PINK,CL 1,90 2600    13  240.5   200 200 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,120   22800   136 2516    167.65  180 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,135   21810   136 2516    160.37  180 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GRANNY SMITH,CL 1,70    2380    14  259 170 220 06/11/14
> 18.50KG CARTON    GRANNY SMITH,CL 1,165   1200    15  277.5   80  80  06/11/14
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

François

Comment: You can put all those `grepl` calls into a single call.  Have a read of the `?regex` man page and the `|` operator.  Those are all vectorized operations, but it will be hard to help without any data

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven.  I have updated the questions with a link to the .csv and the first few rows of the file.

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus.  I did update the question with a link to the file and and the first few rows.

Comment: @Franky You should have specified that you need the first and last part of the `ProductName`.  I wasted my time chasing your code.  Look at your code `"Top Red"`, in the original dataset is `TOPRED`.  So, my solution gave you the result you showed.

Comment: @Franky I updated with another solution `Update2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe all you need is this:

```
apples %>%
  filter(tvaluesold > 10000L & grepl(".*\\d+$", ProductName)) %>%
  mutate(Variety = sub(",.*", "", ProductName),
         Count = as.numeric(sub(".*,", "", ProductName)))
```

Comment: Woo that's exactly it!  A lot more simple and prettier indeed.  That said in don't understand this whole part " & grepl(".*\\d+$", ProductName)".  Also what does the "L" after the 10000 do?

Comment: Since it is inside a `filter`, we subset rows with it. The first part `tvaluesold > 10000L` means tvaluesold values must be > 10000 (I use `10000L` and the L defines the number as integer, but you could just use 10000 instead). The second part, `grepl(".*\\d+$", ProductName)` is a regex matching those rows in ProductName which end with a number.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you want to replace the "prefix" part of "ProductName" with a custom name, you could use `mgsub` from `qdap`.  This will replace the elements in "ProductName" with the modified elements.  A logical `indx` is created based on the `tvaluesold`, then `Variety` column is created with `NA` values, Change the rows in `Variety` that are `TRUE` for the `indx` with the modified `ProductName`.  If you want a new dataset, it is easier to subset by `!is.na(apples$Variety)`

```
library(qdap)
indx <- apples$tvaluesold>10000
v1 <- c('GRANNY SMITH', 'CRIPPS PINK', 'TOPRED',
                    'GOLDEN DELICIOUS','STARKING','BRAEBURN')

 v2 <- c('Granny Smith', 'Cripps Pink', 'Top Red','Golden Delicious',
       'Starking', 'Braeburn')
 apples$Variety <- sub(',.*', '', apples$ProductName)

 apples[indx, 'Variety'] <- mgsub(v1,v2, apples[indx,'Variety']  )
 apples1 <- apples[indx,]

 head(apples1,3)
 #       UnitMass               ProductName tvaluesold tquantitysold tkgsold
 #4 18.50KG CARTON  GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,90      22700           108  1998.0
 #5 18.50KG CARTON          STARKING,CL 1,80      17920           115  2127.5
 #9 18.50KG CARTON GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,120      22800           136  2516.0
 #  avgprice highestprice       date          Variety
 #4   210.19          240 2014-11-06 Golden Delicious
 #5   155.83          230 2014-11-06         Starking
 #9   167.65          180 2014-11-06 Golden Delicious
```

Or using only `base R`

```
 apples$Variety <-  unname(setNames(v2,v1)[sub(',.*', '', apples$ProductName)])
 apples1 <- apples[indx,]
```

For the second case,  you can extract the numbers after the last `,` using `sub` and then use `%in%` to create a logical `indx2`.

```
 val1 <-  as.numeric(sub(".*,", "", apples$ProductName))
 indx2 <-  val1 %in% c(70,80,90,100,110,120,135,150,165)

 apples$Count <- NA
 apples[indx2,'Count'] <-  val1[indx2]
 apples2 <- apples[!is.na(apples$Count),]
 head(apples2,3)
 #       UnitMass              ProductName tvaluesold tquantitysold tkgsold
 #1 18.50KG CARTON     CRIPPS PINK,CL 1,100        200             1    18.5
 #2 18.50KG CARTON       CRIPPS RED,CL 1,70        200             1    18.5
 #4 18.50KG CARTON GOLDEN DELICIOUS,CL 1,90      22700           108  1998.0
 #  avgprice highestprice       date          Variety Count
 #1   200.00          200 2014-11-06      CRIPPS PINK   100
 #2   200.00          200 2014-11-06       CRIPPS RED    70
 #4   210.19          240 2014-11-06 Golden Delicious    90
```

#### Update

You could also use `dplyr` to create the columns

```
library(dplyr)
apples %>%
       filter(tvaluesold >10000) %>% 
       mutate(Variety= setNames(v2,v1)[sub(',.*', '', ProductName)])
```

To create `Count` column

```
 apples %>%
        filter(indx2) %>%
        mutate(Count=val1[indx2])
```

#### Update2

If you want to extract the "first" and "last" of the "ProductName", another option is

```
 library(tidyr)
 res1 <-  extract(apples, ProductName, c("Variety", "Count"),
                   '([^,]+),[^,]+,([^,]+)') %>%
                        filter(tvaluesold >10000L & !is.na(as.numeric(Count))
```

#### data

```
 url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fderyckel/showcases/master/JoburgMarket/JoburgApples.csv'
 library(RCurl)

 x <- getURL(url)
 apples <- read.csv(textConnection(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun.  I know I had to tried with the paste0 but couldn't get the syntax right.  Let me try this.

Comment: @Franky I have a doubt from the data you showed.  Do you want to extract the last numbers after the `,` for `Count` column?

Comment: I really like the dplyr version.  Thanks a lot @akrun.  I've really learned quite a lot from your various versions.